# How to swipe down the page in appium in hybrid app using java.

Tags: java, appium

I unable scroll down page in bottom in hybrid app in appium using java. I am using Appium  v1.6.3

Answer (score 0):

You can use Swipe method to swipe from bottom to up.

 ds.swipe(startx,starty , endx,  endy, 500);

or

you can use scrollto("name of the element")

Answer (score 0):

As it is hybrid app then first we have to change to Native_APP then we have to apply below code

```
Dimension  size = driver.manage().window().getSize();
           System.out.println(size);

           //Find swipe start and end point from screen's with and height.
           //Find starty point which is at bottom side of screen.
           int starty = (int) (size.height * 0.70);
           //Find endy point which is at top side of screen.
           int endy = (int) (size.height * 0.20);
           //Find horizontal point where you wants to swipe. It is in middle of screen width.
           int startx = size.width / 2;
           System.out.println("starty = " + starty + " ,endy = " + endy + " , startx = " + startx);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how i tried a scroll down a side menu and find a logout

//Swipe down the side menu and click on logout

```
 @Test
         public void T4b_logout() throws InterruptedException{  
              size = driver.manage().window().getSize(); //Get the size of screen.
              System.out.println(size);                   
              int starty = (int) (size.height * 0.80);//Find starty point which is at bottom side of screen.
              int endy = (int) (size.height * 0.20);  //Find endy point which is at top side of screen.          
              int startx = size.width / 2; //Find horizontal point where you wants to swipe. It is in middle of screen width.       
              System.out.println("starty = " + starty + " ,endy = " + endy + " , startx = " + startx);   // int startx = size.width;
              driver.swipe(startx, starty, startx, endy, 3000);//Swipe from Bottom to Top.
              Thread.sleep(2000);
              driver.findElement(By.name("Logout")).click();
              driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.Button[@text='Ok']")).click();

         }
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code to swipe down. Interchange the start, end values for swipe up.

```
public void scrollDown(AndroidDriver driver,int swipeTimes, int durationOfSwipe){
        Dimension dimension = driver.manage().window().getSize();

        for (int i=0; i<=swipeTimes;i++){

            int start = (int) (dimension.getHeight() * 0.8);
            int end = (int) (dimension.getHeight() * 0.1);
            int x = (int) (dimension.getWidth()*.5);

            driver.swipe(x, start, x, end, durationOfSwipe);
        }
    }
```